# Apache: apply rules to a URL before they're rewritten

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-expires

I have a simple RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^/r/[0-9]+/(.*)$ /$1
```

This is used for cache-busting. With every web site release I change the url prefix, e.g.:

`/r/17/img/image.jpg` gets `/img/image.jpg`.

I want to apply long expiry headers to these for example

```
<Directory /r>
  Header unset ETag
  FileETag None
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</Directory>
```

Of course this doesn't work because after the RewriteRule is applied, the Directory doesn't match anymore.
How can I apply these rules inside the Directory directive to URLs accessed via `/r/` ?

Thanks!

Comment: `/r` is never a directory, so the rule will never match, neither before nor after the rewrite. You'll have to find a different approach for this (There's `FilesMatch` but I think that has the same problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`<Directory>` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) is for actual existing directories and not just URL paths. Try [`<LocationMatch>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#locationmatch) instead:

```
<LocationMatch "^/r(/|$)">
  Header unset ETag
  FileETag None
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</LocationMatch>
```

Or change `/r` to your actual directory `/img`.